# Chrome SVG background image aliasing bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I've been using an SVG background image on a `textarea` element to provide line numbering for the text displayed in the text area (the line numbers in the following images are from an SVG background image).

However, with Chrome 60.0.3112.113 on Windows 7 I get jagged SVG Display:

[image: Chrome SVG background image opacity/aliasing bug]

As I found out by fiddling, when I edit the `style` properties of the `svg` element to include `opacity: 0.99`, it renders as would be expected (and as Chrome did before):

[image: Chrome SVG Background image with opacity 0.99]

The HTML code to reproduce this is as follows (change `opacity` to 0.99 to see the difference):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>SVG background image opacity/aliasing bug</title>
<style>
#ta {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: red; opacity: 1.0"><text x="4" y="20">0001</text><text x="4" y="38">0002</text><text x="4" y="56">0003</text></svg>')
}
</style>
<body>
<textarea id="ta" cols="40" rows="4">Line 1
Line 2
Line 3</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

If I just place the SVG code into a separate file and open it as plain SVG file (rather than as background in a data-URI) using Chrome it displays as expected.

So while there's the `opacity: 0.99` workaround, I'd like to know why Chrome renders this simplistic SVG incorrectly, or if there's a better workaround, or if there's something fundamentally wrong with the aproach I'm using.

Comment: raise a chrome bug on their bugtracker unless there already is one.

Comment: Another workaround is to place an element (e.g. rect) with a fill behind the text. This also fixes the issue.