# CSS background-image in Chrome is pixelated when resized

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

I realized Chrome renders the CSS background-image differently from `<img />`.

Two same images resized to the same size

- the first with CSS background-image is pixelated
- the second with `<img />` is anti-aliased.

```html
<style>
  .a {
    width: 292px;
    height: 233.594px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.a {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;...");
    background-size: cover;
  }
</style>


<div class="a"></div>
<img class="a" src="data:image/png;..." />
```

[image: preview]

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/tjpn9ecu/3/

Is it possible to force Chrome to enable anti-aliasing for the CSS background-image too?

Comment: Possible workaround is to set opacity 0.99, as per this unanswered question from 2017 https://stackoverflow.com/q/47056025/7073944

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, at least in my case there is no difference.

Comment: The Fiddle looks good on MBP/Chrome 118

Comment: It seems that using `background-size: 100% auto;` instead of `background-size: cover;` achieves this. Not sure if it's viable for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background size in percentage like 100%;

```
background-size: 100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fxau24zo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Any non-zero Z translation will effectively add anti-aliasing and improve the look:

```
div.a {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;...");
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translateZ(1px);  /* Add this */
}
```